# when assigning to void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, void, assign

I thought when assigning a vaule to a pointer, you should use * operator, but I saw a code like

```
char *a;
void *b;
b = "Hello";
a = b;
printf("%s", a);
```

This is legal when I compiled it and prints Hello. Doesn't need a pointer to void dereferencing?

Comment: You thought wrong. `*` is used for assigning to the *pointee*.

Comment: Yes, my terminology is incorrect, but you know what I mean from the code above, right?

Comment: There is no dereferencing involved in your code. There is only assignment of address to a pointer. For this assignment to work l.h.s and r.h.s have to be compatible i.e: of the same data type. A void pointer is a special pointer which can point to any *type*, you can typecast a void pointer back to the exact type it points to. In C you can do this without any explicit cast because it is a weakly typed language while in C++ one needs a explicit cast.

Comment: @Jong-BeomKim: I don't think it's just your "terminology". It feels much more like a genuine misconception, and the fact that you confuse source and target in the language is just a *symptom*. Once you think about this the right way, I'm sure the answer to this question would be totally obvious to you.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: No, I know * is for assigning a value to what the pointer points. My question is just about the pointer to void. My C tutorial shows just a code example above and doesn't explain why you don't need * operator when a pointer to void is used. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I should use the precise terminology.

Comment: `void` isn't a complete type, so a void pointer doesn't really "point to anything", and you cannot dereference it. It's merely a vessel for *storing* opaque pointers. At best you can use it with raw memory manipulating functions like `memmove`, or for in-place construction in C++.

Answer (score 4):

This "works" because a `void *` and a `char *` are able to hold any type of pointer. You could get into trouble, if for example you used `int *a;` instead of `void *a;`.

However, your code isn't dereferencing a `void` pointer, and the printf function converts it to a `char *` when it pulls the argument out of the variable arguments in the list. So there is no dereference of a void pointer in your code. If your pointer didn't perfectly convert to a `char *` (for example if we had an `int *a;`) on some types of machines that don't address bytes without "extra information" (some machines have only 'pointers' to whole machne words, and extra information is used to store which byte within that word you want when reading bytes), then your printf may well have failed to operate correctly ["undefined behaviour"].

Comment: Why would he get in trouble , i am unable to understand.

Comment: Because, on some machines, all pointers are not of the same size. Some pointers (commonly `void *` and `char *`) require a "byte within machine word" extra information. For pointers that point to whole machine words, that wouldn't be required - so if `int` is a machine word, then it won't have that information, and of course, if the information isn't there, some weird thing will happen when the function (such as `printf`) reads back the pointer thinking that the information is actually there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no string type in C. You can treat a `char*` pointing to the beginning of a `char` array as a string. And that's exactly how `printf` treats `a` here.

As far as I remember, the C Standard demands that `char*` and `void*` be interchangeable.

Comment: The interchangeability of `char *` and `void *` isn't actually relevant here, because the conversion is `X *` -> `void *` -> `X *`, and this is guaranteed to be injective for all non-function types `X`, not just `char`.

Comment: Thank you, I think your answer is the closest answer to my question. I googled some time and found that the string literal itself is just an address, so the variable 'b' in the code is a pointer as well as the string literal.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: I think he just pointed out that there was no void* in the old K&R C and char* is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to void does not need dereferencing, infact, dereferencing a void pointer is illegal. You can obviously cast any pointer to a void pointer, and cast a void pointer to any other pointer type.

That's why:

`void *b = "hello world";` worked, so did `char *a = b` and then printing `a` out. 
what happens here is:

```
char *a; // declares a as a pointer to char
void *b; // declares b as a void pointer(which can hold an address)
b = "Hello"; // 'b' now holds the address, that points to the start of "Hello"
a = b; // now, 'a' contains the address that 'b' does
printf("%s", a); // prints the string, starting from the address pointed by 'a'.
```

Hence this is perfectly legal.

Comment: wouldn't int*  b= " hello world " would have worked too ?

Answer (score 0):

`b = "Hello";`
This line allocates a bunch of char memory and assigns its address to `void` pointer variable `b`.

void pointers can store address of any other datatype.
The only limitations with void pointers are:

- cannot dereference void pointer for obvious reasons
- `sizeof(void)` is illegal
- you cannot perform pointer arithmetic on void pointers

However GCC assumes that `sizeof(void)` is 1 and allows pointer arithmetics on void pointers.

`a=b;` This is the typical char pointer `a` initialized to the address contained in void pointer `b`. This is legal but, if misused might have implications.

`printf("%s", a);` This is a simple printf statement.

Everything in this code is fine.

And yes you need to use `*` to assign a value to an allocated memory in pointer:
Eg:

```
   char *c=malloc(sizeof(char));
   *c='a';
```

or

```
   char a='a';
   char *c=&a;
   *c='b';
```

Also you would be using the `*` to initialize another pointer when using double pointers.

```
   char *a=NULL;
   mymalloc(&a);


   void mymalloc(char **a)
   {
     *a=malloc(10);
     return;
   }
```

Hope this helps.